# How to install i3 on Manjaro KDE?

Tags: troubleshooting, manjaro, i3-window-manager

I'm trying to install [i3wm](https://i3wm.org/) on my Manjaro KDE machine.

## What I've done

```
sudo pacman -S i3-wm i3lock i3status
echo "exec i3" >> ~/.xinitrc
```

In my `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`, I commented out the `twm` stuff and also added `exec i3`

```
#twm &
#xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
#xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
#xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
#exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login

exec i3
```

After all that, I restarted my PC but noticed no change. Pressing `alt + H` with multiple windows running doesn't seem to do anything either.

I tried running `startx` but that didn't work:

```
$ startx

/usr/lib/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
^Cxinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: unexpected signal 2
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

`sudo startx` just makes everything stop and blackout. I restarted my PC after some seconds.

What do I have to do to get `i3-wm` working here?

Comment: The sudo attempt is for sure the wrong approach. A GUI should not run with root privileges.

Comment: Have a look :https://forum.manjaro.org/t/i3-wm-and-manjaro-kde/57322/7